# Ruby on Rails: How do I install the mysql gem on 10.6.7 Mac OS X (64bit)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

There seem to be a bunch of blogs and instructions out there to do this, but I think a large issue with them is that they don't specify architecture.. they assume 32bit... which makes me sad =(

Anyone know a good way to install the mysql connector / gem on 64bit snow leopard?
Note: I already have mySQL, and it works just fine.

EDIT:

```
% sudo gem install mysql
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb



Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Edit # 2

```
 % sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql    

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Comment: So `gem install mysql` didn't work?

Comment: what happens when you do `gem install mysql`? I am on Linux, but always 64 bit, the issue was normally with having the mysql headers

Comment: nope, i'll add the output of that.

Comment: This was helpful to me. http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: this command also breaks: sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql i'll add the output ot the question

Comment: The resource that @Felix posted is great; I'd *HIGHLY* recommend that you replace both the Ruby and the MySQL install that come preinstalled on OS X with the latest versions.  Dan Benjamin also has an article on Ruby and Rails on the same blog.  You can also look in to using [brew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) to install these as managed packages.

Comment: While, I'd like to have the latest, and greatest everything, it's not exactly feasible with the app right now =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I hope this helps other people who are having issues:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ; sudo gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -v 2.7 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

got it from this article:

http://www.milindspandit.org/blog/?category_name=technical

Answer (score 0):

I used macports to install mysql, which provides the necessary header files to compile the mysql gem using `gem install mysql`.  I know my mysql installation is 64-bit (`file /path/to/mysql` reports `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`).  I assume the mysql gem is too.  I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't see any mention of macports in your question.